# Level-Sets of the Weierstrass function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, fourier-series

Let $f(x),\,x\in[0,1]$ be [the Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function). For an arbitrary $y\in(0,1)$, what are the properties of the of the level sets,  $R(y):=\{x\big| f(x)=y\}$? I suppose it is infinite. How do we prove it? Are there any other properties?

Comment: I'd imagine that each set $R(y)$ is fractal, for one, so one interesting property would be the fractal dimension of $R(y)$, presumably independent of $y$.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160184/level-sets-of-a-weierstrass-nowhere-differentiable-function